# How can I setup LDAP client authentication?

Tags: 10.10, ldap, openldap

I have set up an OpenLDAP server on Server 1 (running 10.04 desktop) per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenLDAPServer and confirmed that it worked by using LDAP tools to query the LDAP directory. I was also able to configure an OpenSUSE desktop to use this server for LDAP client authentication.

I now want to set up Server 2 (running 10.10 desktop) for LDAP client authentication. I have followed the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication but authentication is not working. It acknowledges that Server 1 is there, but silently fails when I attempt to log in.

Comment: did you try /etc/init.d/nscd stop on the client before logging in? helped me once. Also check all the log files with tail -f messages syslog auth.log ... on every computer so see what's happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem.

Installing `nslcd` helped me.

Comment: I no longer need to do this, so I'm accepting the answer untested